# Custom ListView Item is duplicated in first SubItems column position

Tags: c#, .net, listview, collections, listviewitem

Issue:

The `VisualListViewItem` is duplicated in the first `VisualListViewSubItem` text position when using the designer.

---

Image:

[Design](https://i.stack.imgur.com/st9z1.jpg)

[Debug](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gBHka.jpg)

---

Steps to reproduce:

1. Add `VisuaListViewEx` to your `Form`.
2. Add 2 `VisualListViewColumn`'s to the `VisuaListViewEx`.
3. Add `VisualListViewItem`with text using the `Items` property using the `Designer`.
4. Add a `VisualListViewSubItem` with text to the `SubItems` property in the `VisualListViewItem`.

When doing this dynamically through code it all works as intended. The problem seems to arise when I use the designer it starts doing this after the first debug. Closing the Design Window Tab and reopening it will update it. The SubItem then gets drawn in the next column if one exists to display it. When I open the Items property again I noticed it created a cloned SubItem of the Item.

---

Source:

[VisualListView](https://github.com/DarkByte7/VisualPlus/blob/master/VisualPlus/Toolkit/Controls/DataManagement/VisualListViewEx.cs)

[VisualListViewItem](https://github.com/DarkByte7/VisualPlus/blob/master/VisualPlus/Toolkit/Child/VisualListViewItem.cs)

[VisualListViewSubItem](https://github.com/DarkByte7/VisualPlus/blob/master/VisualPlus/Toolkit/Child/VisualListViewSubItem.cs)

[VisualListViewItemCollection](https://github.com/DarkByte7/VisualPlus/blob/master/VisualPlus/Collections/CollectionsBase/VisualListViewItemCollection.cs)

[VisualListViewSubItemCollection](https://github.com/DarkByte7/VisualPlus/blob/master/VisualPlus/Collections/CollectionsBase/VisualListViewSubItemCollection.cs)

Comment: We need to see the relevant part of the code. Here. You do know that subitems[0] is the Item itself, right?

Comment: It's a few hundred lines so I can't fit it all here. I have therefore updated and provided links to the necessary sources that are being used. Yes I do. But I can't seem to quiet wrap my head around what's causing this or where to look I have debugged my code many times. I'm sure I'm missing something... That is probably right in front of me. So I was just looking for some advice or input.